# stopping a map or filter from iterating the last index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, iteration

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
arr.map((x,i) => arr[i+1] - x)  
// 1,1,1,NaN
```

Is there a way you can use the index in an `Array.map` or `Array.filter` method to compare value with-out comparing the final index to avoid the outcome of `NaN`?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Map produces allways an array of same size. You can only define that a value had to be calculated different

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#slice` to remove the last element before applying `map`.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
console.log(arr.slice(0,-1).map((x,i) => arr[i+1] - x));
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way you could do this would be

```
var mapped = arr.map((x,i) => arr[i+1] - x).filter(x => x);
```

Which is saying filter all the values where x is True

---

But I don't think you can do this with only map. I think map always returns an array of equal length.

You use `reduce` to achieve this though.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]

var reduced = arr.reduce((ids,x,i) => {
    if (i < arr.length-1 ){
        ids.push(arr[i+1] - x)
    }
    return ids
}, []);

console.log(reduced)
```

Outputs

```
[ 1, 1, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just use `Arra.filter()` and return only the value that has a primitive value:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var newArr = arr.map((x,i) => arr[++i] - x)
          .filter(val => val);

console.log(newArr);
```